# How will i get current location of device from google maps.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, cllocationmanager

> I am working in google map in my app. i get default location on map currently. but i need to get current location of device an show it on map. There are lots of solution are there on stackoverlfow, but somehow its not working in my case. These solution work if i add map on default view.Look at my little bit code.

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@import GoogleMaps;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate,    GMSMapViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *maponScreem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end
```

> .m file

```
  self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
longtitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

NSLog(@"%@", latitude);
NSLog(@"%@", longtitude);


GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue]
                                                        longitude:[longtitude floatValue]
                                                             zoom:12];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.maponScreem.bounds camera:camera];
mapView_.delegate = self;
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
[self.maponScreem addSubview: self->mapView_];

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([latitude intValue], [longtitude intValue]);
marker.title = @"Current Location";
marker.map = mapView_;
```

> i get 0.000000 for attitude and longitude.

**EDIT:**
i found solution and look at this how it works. Thanks to you all for answers and support me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];



if (self.locationManager == nil)
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
}
else
{
    nil;
}

if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
{
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
else
{
    nil;
}

self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0) zoom: 16];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.maponScreem.bounds camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
[self.maponScreem addSubview: self->mapView_];

 }

 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
  {
CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
NSString *lasti = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *longi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.longitude];
  //  NSLog(@"%@", lat);
 //  NSLog(@"%@", longi);
   [mapView_ animateToLocation:location.coordinate];


 }
```

Comment: Let me clear if i need to add something in plist file?

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized your locationManager and also you need to ask user permission for location access and set its delegate.Use following code before starting location updates.

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];  //gives alert for location access
    }
```

It will give you user location.

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT**
You should use below method to receive location updates

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
```

The method you have used is deprecated.

Comment: ok so this code also work for get permission for location?

Comment: and where should i place this code in viewdidload?

Comment: Yes add it in viewDidLoad before calling "startUpdatingLocation".Setting delegate will provide you location updates in "didUpdateToLocation" function.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet GMSMapView *googleMapView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

- (void)showCurrentLocation {
    _googleMapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
            GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude 
                                                                    longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude 
                                                                         zoom:17.0];
            [_googleMapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
        //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you..

```
 - (IBAction)btnSetDistance:(id)sender {

locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

locationManager.distanceFilter =//as per your requirment;

if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

**This is important**

Enable Background Modes from--- Project, Capabilities Tab, and choose Location Updates...

you should check it on device instead of simulator.